# Remove SQL, CSS code from JSON file

Tags: python, css, sql, json, regex

I have scrapped a webpage and ended up with this; all strings stored in a json format where I have the required text and some SQL and CSS code. How can I remove this using python. I have the following code to clean up the JSON file but it not working. what will be the regex which can match all SQL queries and CSS code. I tried a lot but all in vain.

JSON FORMAT:

```
{

    "text": ["Search Logic",
    "SELECT c.company_id\nFROM companies c\nLEFT JOIN .........",
    "Check all",
    "Uncheck all",
    "Trail Counts",
    "Trails modified",
    "\n\t\t        body {\n            background-color: #fff8dc;\n        }\n    \n\t\t",
    ".gm-style .gm-style-cc span,.gm-style .gm-style-cc a,.gm-style .gm-style-mtc div{font-size:10px}",
    "@media print {  .gm-style .gmnoprint, .gmnoprint {    display:none  }}@media screen {  .gm-style .gmnoscreen, .gmnoscreen {    display:none  }}",
    ".gm-style{font-family:Roboto,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:11px;font-weight:400;text-decoration:none}.gm-style img{max-width:none}"
      ]
 }
```

Code:

```
import json
from pprint import pprint

with open('input.json') as data_file:    
    data = json.load(data_file)

target = open("output", 'w')

for dic in data:
    for line in dic["text"]:
        if "background-color" or "gm-style" in line:
            continue
        line = line.strip()
        if line != "":
            target.write(line.encode('ascii','ignore'))
            target.write("\n")
```

Comment: Due to the sheer complexity of what you're trying to match, I would suggest not trying to use regex here since it won't work well. I, however, am not sure of a particularly good alternative

Comment: You can try to use validators/parsers to CSS and SQL, and if it's not a valid CSS/SQL, you get the Text... CSS Parser Python: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cssutils/ and SQL Parser Python: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sqlparse

Comment: Not a good solution, though...

Comment: Are you sure you can't fix this in the scraping code? That would be best.